# Ancestors in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to create a predicate that receives only one argument and returns all ancestors of the passed argument:

```
% parents example:
parent(jaime, rog)
parent(sirris, anri)
parent(gywn, gwyndolin)

ancestor(Y, X) :- parent(Y, X).
ancestor(X) :- parent(Y, X), ancestor(Y, X).
```

It returns only true, but I want it to return the names. (It requires to pass just one argument!)

Answer (score 1):

Your second clause is another predicate, `ancestor/1`, so with *one* parameter, not *two*.

You can make a recursive call with:

```
ancestor(X, Y) :-
    parent(X, Y).
ancestor(X, Z) :-
    parent(X, Y),
    ancestor(Y, Z).
```

You can make use of [**`findall/3`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)
to find all ancestors:

```
ancestors(X, Ys) :-
    findall(Y, ancestor(X, Y), Ys).
```